# Making uibarbuttonitems fade

Tags: uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, rightbarbuttonitem

I have a navigation bar that is set up and controlled completely with code. So it does not show up in IB. I have a button appear by "self.navigationitem.rightbarbutton = myButton;"
An I make it go away by setting it equal to NIL. What I am wondering is how could I make it fade in and out?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found what worked best for me

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:myButton animated:YES];
```

And then

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
```

To make it fade out.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift version**

fade in: `navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(myButton, animated: true)`

fade out: `navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(nil, animated: true)`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no built in way to animate this for bar button items in a navigation bar. UIBarButtonItem is not a view or a control so it does not have animatable properties like alpha.

For bar button items in a UIToolbar, there is a way to animate. See this answer for details:

[Is it possible to use Core Animation to fade out a UIBarButtonItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815784/is-it-possible-to-use-core-animation-to-fade-out-a-uibarbuttonitem)