# Fade Out/In UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uibarbuttonitem

I have looked around but can't find a definitive answer. I need to fade in and out a couple of `UIBarButtonItems`, simple as that. How can I?

If I can't fade a `UIBarButtonItem` in anyway whatsoever, then what could I do as an alternative?

Comment: I believe you will find your answer at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815784/is-it-possible-to-use-core-animation-to-fade-out-a-uibarbuttonitem?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't fade `UIBarButtonItems` themselves because they are not views.
**But** you can init a plain `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view (`UIButton` is the best) and fade that one. For that you need to store your buttons somewhere.